# Getting a set of template references based on header viewchild

Tags: angular

I have the following code

```
<div #header>
 <ng-container *ngFor="Dynamic Value">
   <child-one #childone></child-one>
 </ng-container>
 <input type="number" #valueone>
 <ng-container *ngFor="Dynamic Value">
   <child-two #childtwo></child-two>
 </ng-container>
 <input type="number" #valuetwo>
</div>
```

viewchild is used on header, is there any way to get separate lists of viewchildren based on references used in template using the header viewchild. I know I can directly use separate view children on each template reference to get their query list but Im looking for an approach where I can have one main viewchild and querying references based on it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not possible what you are asking for. `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` query for elements during rendering and start viewing them directly after that. Once rendering is done there is no way to start viewing for elements with those decorators.

I can help you find the child references from the div using `id` prop. I name it same as `#` so afterwards you could use these to reference the elements.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  @ViewChild('header', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) header!: any;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.header);
    let queryForIdArray: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.header.nativeElement.children.length; i++) {
      let child = this.header.nativeElement.children[i];
      if (child.localName.includes('hello')) {
        if (!queryForIdArray.includes(String(child.id)))
          queryForIdArray.push(child.id);
      }
    }

    console.log('child element refs to find: ', queryForIdArray);
    // This is strongly not advised to do
    for (let ref of queryForIdArray) {
      var child = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#' + ref);
      console.log(child);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div #header>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <hello #childone id="childone" name="Angular" ></hello>
  </ng-container>
  <input type="number" #valueone>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <hello #childtwo id="childtwo" name="Angular" ></hello>
  </ng-container>
  <input type="number" #valuetwo>
 </div>
```

You could however use ElementRef constructor and reference it yourself but it is strongly advised not to do so. https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchildren-example-rqtn21?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I want invoke a get method in the child class, since I'm not getting an instance of the component class I cant access any properties or methods